# Recursive WITH in Postgres for getting developers id's

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a task - I need to get id's of developers (lets name them 1) who worked with the given developer on the same projects, then to get id's of developers (lets name them 2) who worked with (1) on the same projects, and finally to get the id's of developers who worked with (2) on the same projects. 
I don't really understand how I should do this task. It's no problem getting the (1), but the next layers are just repeating when I run my code. Can anybody help me or just give an idea to help me out?

Table structure:
developer_id - INTEGER
project_id - INTEGER

Comment: So you want a query that returns everyone that is working on a certain project or everyone that works on the same project as a certain developer?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.